# How to resolve importerror while importing tensorflow in jupyer notebook?

Tags: tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

ImportError: cannot import name 'multi_worker_mirrored_2x1_gpu_noshare' from 'tensorflow.python.distribute.strategy_combinations' (C:\Users\mizan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\strategy_combinations.py)

I also reinstall this package by

`conda create -n tf tensorflow conda activate tf` 
I just want to know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This seems you are trying to use the tensorflow gpu in your system but it has not setup correctly.

Please refer to the [TF install](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#hardware_requirements) page to install tensorflow with GPU support as per your system OS. Please check the System/Hardware requirements and install all the software(Nvidia driver, CUDA, cuDNN) and set the path correctly for GPU setup.

**Note:**

> GPU support on native-Windows is only available for 2.10 or earlier
> versions. Starting in TF 2.11, CUDA build is not supported for
> Windows. For using TensorFlow GPU on Windows, you will need to
> build/install TensorFlow in WSL2 or use tensorflow-cpu with
> TensorFlow-DirectML-Plugin.